# Unable to get screenshot of window through winapi

Tags: node.js, winapi

Using the [Node.js ffi-napi package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi), I'm attempting to get a buffer of bitmap data from a screenshot of a given window or desktop if no window handle is supplied. To that end, I'm trying to port the c++ example from the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image) and making the api calls through ffi-napi.

Even though all the api calls come back without errors, I only end up with a buffer filled with 0s. I've traced it down to a few potential pieces that might be causing it but I don't know which piece is incorrect and how to fix it.

- Even though my call to BitBlt is returning true, the pixel values I get from calling GetPixel on my source window dc is returning correct values but when I call GetPixel on my memory dc, I get 0s.
- My call to GetObjectA seems to be populating the BITMAP struct I created, (my structs are just extensions of buffers), except the last 8 bytes which is supposed to hold the pointer to the bitmap data is all 0s.
- My call to GetDIBits is returning 1080 which is the correct number of rows it should have read from the bitmap data but the buffer I get back is all 0s.

My guess is that BitBlt didn't actually copy the desktop dc to the memory dc even though it's returning true and I don't know why that is. I've also tried running the calculator app and passing in the dc to the screenshot function as well and even though it returns the appropriate items, the buffer I get back is still all 0s.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my node.js code

```
function screenshot(hWnd = null) {
    let hdcWindow = null;
    let hdcMemDC = null;
    let hbmScreen = null;
    let hDIB = null;

    try {
        if (!hWnd) hWnd = user32.GetDesktopWindow();
        console.log('hWnd', hWnd);

        // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client area of the window.
        hdcWindow = user32.GetDC(hWnd);
        console.log('hdcWindow', hdcWindow);
        const rcClient = new win32_structs.RECT();
        user32.GetClientRect(hWnd, rcClient);
        console.log('rcClient', rcClient);

        // Create a compatible DC and bitmap
        hdcMemDC = gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
        console.log('hdcMemDC', hdcMemDC);
        hbmScreen = gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top);
        console.log('hbmScreen', hbmScreen);
        const hPrevDC = gdi32.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);
        console.log('hPrevDC', hPrevDC);

        // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
        const bitBltRes = gdi32.BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 0, 0, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top, hdcWindow, 0, 0, apiConstants.SRCCOPY);
        const pixelWnd = gdi32.GetPixel(hdcWindow, 0, 0);
        const pixelMem = gdi32.GetPixel(hdcMemDC, 0, 0);
        console.log('pixelWnd', pixelWnd);
        console.log('pixelMem', pixelMem);
        console.log('bitBltRes', bitBltRes);

        // Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP
        const bmpScreen = new win32_structs.BITMAP();
        const getObjectRes = gdi32.GetObjectA(hbmScreen, bmpScreen.length, bmpScreen);
        console.log('getObjectRes', getObjectRes);
        console.log('bmpScreen.length', bmpScreen.length);
        console.log('bmpScreen', bmpScreen);

        const bi = new win32_structs.BITMAPINFOHEADER();
        bi.biSize = bi.length;
        bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
        bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
        bi.biPlanes = 1;
        bi.biBitCount = 32;
        bi.biCompression = apiConstants.BI_RGB;
        bi.biSizeImage = 0;
        bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bi.biClrUsed = 0;
        bi.biClrImportant = 0;
        console.log('bi', bi);

        const dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;
        console.log('dwBmpSize', dwBmpSize);

        // Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that
        // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc
        // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
        // hDIB = kernel32.GlobalAlloc(apiConstants.GHND, dwBmpSize);
        // const lpBitmap = kernel32.GlobalLock(hDIB);
        const lpBitmap = new Buffer.alloc(dwBmpSize);

        // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap and copies them into buffer lpbitmap
        const getDIBitsRes = gdi32.GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0, bmpScreen.bmHeight, lpBitmap, bi, apiConstants.DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        console.log('getDIBitsRes', getDIBitsRes);
        console.log('lpBitmap', lpBitmap);

        for (const c of lpBitmap) {
            if (c > 0) {
                console.log(c);
                break;
            }
        }

        // clean up
        if (hDIB != null) {
            kernel32.GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
            kernel32.GlobalFree(hDIB);
        }

        if (hbmScreen != null) gdi32.DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
        if (hdcMemDC != null) gdi32.DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
        if (hdcWindow != null) user32.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);


        return lpBitmap;

    } catch (err) {
        // clean up memory on errors
        if (hDIB != null) {
            kernel32.GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
            kernel32.GlobalFree(hDIB);
        }

        if (hbmScreen != null) gdi32.DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
        if (hdcMemDC != null) gdi32.DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
        if (hdcWindow != null) user32.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);

        throw err;
    }
}
```

Here's my console log:

```
hWnd 65552
hdcWindow 83954845

rcClient <Buffer@0x000001BE188E8670 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 07 00 00 38 04 00 00, _structProps: { left: { offset: 0, dataType: 'long' }, top: { offset: 4, dataType: 'long' }, right: { offset: 8, dataType: 'long' 
    }, bottom: { offset: 12, dataType: 'long' } }, left: 0, top: 0, right: 1920, bottom: 1080>
    
hdcMemDC 1375804638
hbmScreen 990189696
hPrevDC 8716303
pixelWnd { r: 231, g: 234, b: 237 }
pixelMem { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }
bitBltRes true
getObjectRes 32
bmpScreen.length 32

bmpScreen <Buffer@0x000001BE188C5CC0 00 00 00 00 80 07 00 00 38 04 00 00 00 1e 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00, 
    _structProps: { bmType: { offset: 0, dataType: 'long' }, bmWidth: { offset: 4, dataType: 'long' }, bmHeight: { offset: 8, dataType: 'long' }, bmWidthBytes: { offset: 12, dataType: 'long' }, bmPlanes: { offset: 16, dataType: 'uint' }, bmBitsPixel: { offset: 18, dataType: 'uint' }, pointerPadding: { offset: 20, dataType: 'long' }, bmBits: { offset: 24, dataType: 'ulonglong' } }, 
     bmType: 0, bmWidth: 1920, bmHeight: 1080, bmWidthBytes: 7680, bmPlanes: 1, bmBitsPixel: 32, pointerPadding: 0, bmBits: 0n>
     
bi <Buffer@0x000001BE188C5540 28 00 00 00 80 07 00 00 38 04 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00, 
    _structProps: { biSize: { offset: 0, dataType: 'ulong' }, biWidth: { offset: 4, dataType: 'long' }, biHeight: { offset: 8, dataType: 'long' }, biPlanes: { offset: 12, dataType: 'uint' }, biBitCount: { offset: 14, dataType: 'uint' }, biCompression: { offset: 16, dataType: 'ulong' }, biSizeImage: { offset: 20, dataType: 'ulong' }, biXPelsPerMeter: { offset: 24, dataType: 'long' }, biYPelsPerMeter: { offset: 28, dataType: 'long' }, biClrUsed: { offset: 32, dataType: 'ulong' }, biClrImportant: { offset: 36, dataType: 'ulong' } }, 
    biSize: 40, biWidth: 1920, biHeight: 1080, biPlanes: 1, biBitCount: 32, biCompression: 0, biSizeImage: 0, 
    biXPelsPerMeter: 0, biYPelsPerMeter: 0, biClrUsed: 0, biClrImportant: 0>
    
dwBmpSize 8298585
getDIBitsRes 1080

lpBitmap <Buffer@0x000001BE18AED040 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 8298535 more bytes>
```

Comment: I've recreated a C++ sample with the step of your sample, and it works for me, can you show how you declare winapi in user32 and gdi32 and RECT struct?

Comment: I was able to get it working, it was my SRCCOPY enumeration, when I googled it, the first link I clicked on for Microsoft said it was 0xCC, but after going down many wrong paths, I found a different source that said 0xCC0020 and that worked.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem, I guess you misused the values in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wmf/1605dd68-a635-4639-ab81-99ff3e3fc5a3). It is actually an operation index.

Comment: Yep, that's the document I originally found. Took a really long time before I revisited that to confirm.

Comment: hello, can you provide a full code example? I'm learning use node-ffi but I don't know how to define the correct gdi32 type, very appreciate!

Comment: @frankw I was able to reproduce the working code, and have published it in the npm package named `windows-ffi`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69063161/2441655

Answer (score 0):

The OP mentioned they were able to get their code working in the end, with a simple fix to one of the constants. However, that doesn't help other readers so much, because they don't have the full code for it; so I thought I would try to reproduce the working code that they had. (thanks to @vincitego for the starting point!)

After a whole lot of trial and error, I was able to get my reproduction working, and have published the solution as a component in my Windows FFI library here: https://github.com/Venryx/windows-ffi

Usage:

```js
import {VRect, CaptureScreenshot, GetForegroundWindowHandle} from "windows-ffi";

// First capture a screenshot of a section of the screen.
const screenshot = CaptureScreenshot({
    windowHandle: GetForegroundWindowHandle(), // comment to screenshot all windows
    rectToCapture: new VRect(0, 0, 800, 600),
});

// The image-data is now stored in the `screenshot.buffer` Buffer object.
// Access it directly (and cheaply) using the helper functions on `screenshot`.
for (let x = 0; x < 800; x++) {
    console.log(`Pixel color at [${x}, 0] is:`, screenshot.GetPixel(x, 0).ToHex_RGB());
}
```

You can use the library as packaged, or, if you prefer, just reference its source-code and extract the parts you need. The main module for screenshot-capturing can be [seen here](https://github.com/Venryx/windows-ffi/blob/master/Source/Helpers/ScreenCapture.ts).